# Can a gas pipe/tube run under floor joists?

Tags: gas, building-regulations

I have a flexible gas tube connecting to a gas stove which goes under the floor joists in my basement. Can this area be enclosed with drywall? Does it have to be run through the joists like electrical?

EDIT: Just realized this is the type of piping used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrugated_stainless_steel_tubing

Comment: Does the flex tubing go through the floor? How (and where) is it connected with the gas line in the basement? Pictures from the basement might help, because as I envision this it might not *currently* meet code.

Comment: I will try to add a picture tomorrow. The gas line goes into a gas stove that is in the basement. Never goes through the floor. Just under the floor joists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping run concealed in finished spaces has to be installed through the joists and protected from physical damage. Or be run in black or galvanized steel. Or you could box the pipe run and shield it. Also, a flexible appliance connector has a length limit of 6 feet.

Code quotes are from the 2012 IRC

SECTION G2415 (404) PIPING SYSTEM INSTALLATION

> 62415.7 (404.7) Protection against physical damage. In 
>   concealed locations, where piping other than black or galvanized steel is installed through holes or notches in wood studs, joists, rafters or similar members less than 1.5 inches (38 mm) from the nearest edge of the member, the pipe shall be protected by shield plates. Shield plates shall be a minimum of 1/16-inch-thick (1.6 mm) steel, shall cover the area of the pipe where the member is notched or bored and shall extend a minimum of 4 inches (102 mm) above sole plates, below top plates 
>   and to each side of a stud, joist or rafter.

SECTION G2422 (411) APPLIANCE CONNECTIONS

> 62422.1.1 (411.1.1) Protection from damage. Connectors and tubing shall be installed so as to be protected against physical damage.
>
> 62422.1.2.1 (411.1.3.1) Maximum length. Connectors shall not exceed 6 feet (1829rnm) in overall length. Measurement shall be made along the 
>   centerline of the connector. Only one connector shall be used for each appliance.
>
> *Exception: Rigid metallic piping used to connect an appliance to the piping system shall be permitted to have a total length greater than 6 feet (1829 mm), provided that the connecting pipe is sized as part of the 
>   piping system in accordance with Section G2413 and the location of the equipment shutoff valve complies with Section G2420.5.*

Have you considered a drop ceiling in this area?

Good luck with your project!

Comment: This section is also relevant:  404.5 Piping in concealed locations. Portions of a piping system installed in concealed locations shall not have unions, tubing fittings, right and left couplings, bushings, compression couplings and swing joints made by combinations of fittings.

Comment: Well great, the length of the Flexible tube is more than 6 feet. Can I just cut notches in the joists, put the tube in the notch, and use shield plates to cover the opening?

Comment: Can CSST be used under the joist? I believe this is the type I am using.

Comment: I would **never** notch a joist on the bottom that is the part that is stressed the most by the weight  sitting on top of it. CSST is allowed to be run in lengths longer than 6 feet. (NOT the gray corregated appliance connectors.) You should disconnect one end after you turn off the gas of course and re-route the line through holes drilled in the middle third of the floor joists. Here is a link to an installation guide for CSST: http://www.proflexcsst.com/docs/ProFlex%20CSST%20Installation%20Guide.pdf